# Windows 10 connect to wifi AP without active user

Tags: powershell, windows-10, wifi

I am running into an issue connecting to a wifi AP using Windows 10 PC.

The AP is located on an embedded device, amd uses WPA2-personal security. The AP can be enabled by our testsetup for certain testcases. The idea is to let Windows connect to the AP in these tests.
I am able to manually connect to the AP when it is active. However, when I try it when there is no active user (e.g. headless/CI setup), I get an error.

The command and reply I use when manually connecting (using a saved WiFi profile named "Test_AP.xml"):

```
PS C:\projects> netsh wlan add profile user=current filename=Test_AP.xml; netsh wlan connect name=Test_AP interface="Wi-Fi"
Profile Test_AP is added on interface Wi-Fi.
Connection request was completed successfully.
```

When I try with no activ user (e.g. headless/CI setup), the reply is:

```
Profile Test_AP is added on interface Wi-Fi.
The network specified by profile "Test_AP" is not available to connect.
```

I was able to reproduce it, by adding a sleep command before executing the powershell commands, and immediatelly disconnecting my remote session to the PC. When I reconnect after a while, I see this error.

I already tried adding to profile to all users, but to no avail.

Does anybody know why Windows is not able to connect to a wireless network in this case? Or any inspiration what I can improve?

Kind regards